# how to include sub-index.html in index.html

Tags: html

I have an old-index.html for a old-touchscreen project(800*600 pixel), now I have a much larger touchscreen(1920*1024) and have more displays, a new-index.html. I prefer to keep all info of old-index.html in new-index.html in a simple way, i.e, leave a 800*600 space in the new touchscreen, and display the exact size of the old touchscreen.  The last way is to merge everything of old-index.html into new-index.html, but too much work. if there is a way I could "insert" old-index.html into new-index.html (I define a special area in new-index.html,and then force old-index.html inside this area.....), that will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IFRAME : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp to load the entire old html inside the new page without any CSS or JS clashing.

i.e.

```
<iframe style="width:800px; height:600px; border:none" src="/old-index.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but the strange thing is the insert page does not completely fit the border of the area I defined, I use boostrap , I tried style="position:absolute;" or style="text-align: center;", the inserted page always be shifted to the right around 10pixels, and leave around 10 pxels on the left. The padding of the area just could not control the inside inserted frame,

Comment: Glad to help. Gor the layout problem, if you have a code sample/pen, post a question and we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Just have all the old stuff inside a section tag, and make the new one responsive to change the dimensions of the old one smoothly on a larger viewport that I think you are trying to say. I don't know for sure if I understood the problem.

Comment: thanks, new touchscreen size is fixed, for example, 1920*1024, the old touchscreen size is 800*600, so in new touchscreen 1920*1024 I will define a 800*600 area to keep all the old info. and add new info outside of this 800*600 area. I have updated the question, hope this will make my question clear.

Comment: Oh, so following up on my answer, I think CSS flex boxes should do the trick if you have not looked over it already. You may have everything of the older stuff inside one of the flex elements and order it the way you want with the whatever the new page would have. You do have to kind of put things together but this is the easiest way in my eyes. I hope my answer was helpful. Best of luck!